# maven module dependency and issue with large image size in Docker

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a maven java project that has the following structure:

```
-my-project
  -audit
  -domain
  -persistence
  -source1
  -source2
  -source3
  -utils
  -validation
 pom.xml
 DockerFile
```

My project includes multiple modules. `source1`, `source2`, `source3` has dependency on the other modules such as audit, domain, validation etc.

I am using the maven assembly plugin to aggregate the project output along with its dependencies, modules, and other files into a single, runnable package.

I have assembly descriptors for each sources and deploy them as separate bundles.

I only have a single `DockerFile` used to create image for the services `source1` `source2` etc.

DockerFile:

```
FROM java...

ARG ARTIFACT_URL

# User Configs Stages...

RUN curl -o ./source1.zip -L "${ARTIFACT_URL}&a=source1-bundle"
RUN curl -o ./source2.zip -L "${ARTIFACT_URL}&a=source2-bundle"

RUN unzip ./source1.zip -d ./source1/
RUN unzip ./source2.zip -d ./source2/
```

I then have docker-compose for each sources.

The problem with this approach is `source2` contains bundle for `source1` in it's image. My images are quite large and I want to make them thinner. I have read up on using multi stage builds and using thinner base images etc but I am struggling to see how I can change the above dockerfile/my approach to create thinner images.

my question is, what approach I can take to make my images thinner? Can I use multi-stage builds in this instance to help this cause?

Maybe i can use different image for the dependent modules audit, domain etc and base source1 image off that image?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, a different image from a different source would be ideal. You can use those separate images from docker-compose as separate services.